# How to install Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 7 (32-bit)?

Tags: windows-7, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5, backwards-compatibility

I do have Windows 7 32-bit (Ultimate), this is a screen shot that shows the systems features:

[image: Image 2]

I need to install visual studio 2013 but it shows this dialog:

[image: Image 1]

I guess that this problem can be solved by installing some required files that makes Windows 7 functions as Windows 8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [System Requirements](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-ultimate-with-msdn-vs#Fragment_SystemRequirements), you need to install [Windows 7 Service Pack 1](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/install-windows-7-service-pack-1), which (judging by your screen shot) you are currently not running.

Comment: Great! but can i install the Service Pack1 as a standalone ? or i have to install the whole "Windows 7 Service Pack1" System ?

Comment: It's just a patch.  Check your Windows Updates.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install Windows 7 sp1.

The System Requirements of Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 are as follows:

Supported Operating System

Windows 7 Service Pack 1, Windows 8, Windows 8.1, Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1, Windows Server 2012, Windows Server 2012 R2

Hardware Requirements:

1.6 GHz or faster processor
1 GB of RAM (1.5 GB if running on a virtual machine)
10 GB of available hard disk space
5400 RPM hard disk drive
DirectX 9-capable video card that runs at 1024 x 768 or higher display resolution
Additional Requirements:

On Windows 8.1 and Windows Server 2012 R2, KB2883200 (available through Windows Update) is required

More information, please refer to:

## Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013

http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=40778

Please check your Operating System.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I found a solution. A heavy one. You delete the version installed with Revo Uninstaller with Advanced mode - in order to remove registries and connected software. After that I used TuneUp 2014 registry editor and searched for "Visual Studio". It found 900 more entries in the registry. I deleted all of them and installed clean again. It solved my problem.