# Installing Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation, windows64

I would like to install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7 64-bit.

During set-up i got below issue. How to over come this

[image]

How to overcome this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7)

Comment: Yes, but error what i got is different. any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate on Windows 7 (32-bit)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25269679/how-to-install-visual-studio-2013-ultimate-on-windows-7-32-bit)

Answer (score 0):

Check the windows updates. If anything is there to update, update it first.
Services pack 1 should be updated to install visual studio 2013